# Loading a data file in Netezza Emulator

Tags: netezza

I am trying to load some data in a remote Netezza Server through VMWare Virtual Machine. The command I used is

nzload -u admin -pw password -db system -t testtable -delim ',' -df 'C:\test\testtable.csv'

But I am receiving an error - dataobject 'home/nz/C:\test\testtable.csv' not found

I beleive that I have to either reset my home directory or transfer the file to the nNetezza homme directory. Since the Netezza is installed in a remote host, how can this be done through VM?

I do not have Netezza ODBC driver so cannot use 'Remotesource ODBC'

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To complete this task there are several ways present, you can choose any from below -

```
1) Use winscp or any other ftp tool to transfer the file on Netezza box and then do nzload.
2) You can install netezza client more details you can find at - [http://bajajvarun.blogspot.in/][1]
3) You can transfer your file with Agnity workbench.
```